# What is the difference of “speak at” and “speak of”?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

I am looking for the exact meaning of the verb “to speak at”. When we use **speak at something** instead of **speak of something**?
For example what is the meaning of this sentence:

> They allow him to speak at every hazard.

Comment: Where did you find this *hazard* sentence?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. They allow him to speak **at** every hazard.

This sentence is ambiguous.

In theory, it could mean either of the following:

- They allow him to speak whenever they encounter a hazard.
  → "Now that we've encountered another hazard, you can take your gag out if you have something to say."
- They allow him to address himself to every hazard they encounter.
  → "Hi, hazard. I'm glad to meet you.")

But neither of those interpretations mean the same thing as the following:

> 2. They allow him to speak **of** every hazard.

- They allow him to orate on the topic of every hazard they will or might encounter.
  → "On this journey, we'll encounter many hazards. The first is well documented . . .")

Comment: How do you read this line of Whitman: “I harbor for good or bad, I permit to **speak at** every hazard.”

Comment: @Connoisseur I'd say it's likely similar to my first interpretation—they speak up when there's a hazard—but it's difficult to say without hearing more. And poetic phrases like this often remain subjective.